# Responsive CSS: Two divs. One fixed size right-floated. One varying size. Stacked if size < threshold, one row if size >= threshold

Tags: css

I have a div that contains two other divs. The first div has varying width. The second div has a fixed width.

a) When the width of the screen (will use a media query) is less than a threshold I would like the divs to be in two separate rows. One row floated to the left and the other floated to the right but stacked on top of each other with the fixed row underneath and floated to the right of the varying width row.

```
-------------------------------
| varying width div           |
-------------------------------
            -------------------
            | fixed width div |
            -------------------
```

b) When the width of the screen is greater than or equal to a threshold (again media queries) I would like the two divs to be in one row. With the varying width div using up the remainder of the width.

```
---------------------- -------------------
| varying width div  | | fixed width div |
---------------------- -------------------
```

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amirjsf/bC5DZ/) provides a detailed example of what I want along with what I've tried.

Margin-float approach: An approach that works for medium and large sized divs, but not small sized divs. If I used a media query to use different css for the small sized divs then right column would appear above the left column since floats depend on html order:

```html
<div>
    <div class="col2">
        Fixed text
    </div>        
    <div class="col1">
        Varying length text goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.approach-group.margin-float .col1 {
    margin-right: 100px;
}

.approach-group.margin-float .col2 {
    width: 100px;
    float: right;
}
```

Float-only approach: An approach that works for small and large sized divs, but not medium sized divs. Also this approach has undefined behavior because it uses [floats without a width](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/introduction.htm).

```html
<div>
    <div class="col1">
        Varying length text goes here
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
        Fixed text
    </div>        
</div>
```

```css
.approach-group.float-both .col1 {
    float: left;
}

.approach-group.float-both .col2 {
    width: 100px;
    float: right;
}
```

I wanted to know if there were any CSS approaches to solving this problem.

Additionally, if you know of a way to do this without media queries at all and just a min-width specification on column 1 (forcing two rows if the width is below a threshold) that would be even more amazing.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bootstrap way to reach you goal.
For example:

We have 2 divs with different adaptive behavior

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-x-6">1</div>
  <div class="col-x-6">2</div>
</div>
```

Lets **.col-x-6** - set default width or special width for some screen resolution.
Next step is add extra class to change width for other resolutio

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-x-6 col-y-12">1</div>
  <div class="col-x-6 col-y-6"">2</div>
</div>
```

col-y-12 overrides col-x-6 if screen fits some resolution.

So you can easily set col-y-* and col-x-* width in different @media wrap.

```
@media (min-width: 480px) {
    .col-x-6{
        width: 50%;
    }

    .col-x-12{
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .col-y-6{
        width: 100%;
    }

    .col-y-12{
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

In case you would like to display blocks on one line, one with fixed width, second with fluid (rest of parent container) you can use **display: table** on **.row** and **display: table-cell** on **.colx**

Fore more information checkout [bootstrap page](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: The problem is the bootstrap way uses percentages for the column widths. I want the right column to have a fixed width and the left column to consume the rest of the space.

Comment: in this case you can change % to px and you can change floating direction in media rules

Comment: Unfortunately only one of the columns is fixed width. What would I specify as the width for the varying width column?

Comment: oh, in this case you can override display property to display: table-cell on .col and display: table; on container - that can help you to set one column fixed width and other varying.

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you! Do you want to add a new answer or edit your existing one. I've updated my jsfiddle with your "Table cell approach." Thanks again for answering this question!

Comment: @Amir, glad to help) answer updated, if you found it usefull please mark it as right

Answer (score 3):

@Evgeniy has provided a good solution. I updated [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amirjsf/bC5DZ/) with his approach (see solution #1). I'm giving him the check mark but I thought I'd be more explicit about the solution:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="col1">
        Varying length text goes here
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
        Fixed text
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.approach-group.table-cell .container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;    
}

.approach-group.table-cell .col1 {
    display: table-cell;
}

.approach-group.table-cell .col2 {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100px;
}
```

This solution also allows me to use media queries to eliminate the styles above and instead have col2 pulled-right under col1 when the screen size is below a certain threshold (the key flaw with the margin-float approach).

For more details go to [the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amirjsf/bC5DZ/).